# Postgres IN clause using nested select statement behaviour

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgres but can't see what is wrong with my query here:

```
with a as (SELECT unnest(string_to_array(ags_roles, ',')) AS ident FROM all_roles where id = 100)
select name from all_identities where identity_name IN (select ident from a)
```

Now the data returned from `a` above is (3 records):

```
1 007
2 008
3 009
```

Within my other table `all_identities` there are five records that have the `identity_name` of 007 and three records that have the `identity_name` of 009

The problem that I am facing and unsure why, is that my query above is only returning the five records related to `007` and nothing from `009`. I expected to see 8 records.

Any help on what I am doing wrong as unfortunately I can't see it?

Comment: Provide a complete test case that produces the behavior.  My guess at your actual data/structure produced the expected/correct result.  Instead of an english description, better to just include (in the question) the `CREATE TABLE` statements, with `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Example, with `CTE` terms to provide the test table data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=32928975fdf21d8b9e32bdeec2f371b2